# System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I have two dlls right next to each other in a directory. When I load an assembly invoke a method from DLL A onto DLL B then invoke a method from DLL B back onto DLL A, but it fails at the last step and throws the following error

```
 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
    at ServerSDK.BootStrapper.GetPlayerSteamID(UInt16 playerid)
```

And here is the code.

```
public void Init()
{            
    string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string file = Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "NetworkSystem.dll");
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
    type = assembly.GetType("ScriptingAPI.ScriptEngine");

    getSteamMethod = type.GetMethod("GetSteamID", new Type[] { typeof(ushort) });
    Console.WriteLine("bootstrap module executed");       
}

public static string GetPlayerSteamID(ushort playerid)
{
    var steamid = getSteamMethod.Invoke((object)type, new object[1] { playerid });
    return steamid.ToString();
}
```

and here is the method that from DLL A I am attempting to invoke

```
public string GetSteamID(ushort playerID)
{
    Console.WriteLine(playerID.GetType().Name);
    return connectedPlayers[playerID].steamID;
}
```

Also I feel like I need something like Activator.GetInstance instead of CreateInstance as the DLL is already running and if i was to use CreateInstance it would in turn throw null reference exceptions.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Can you show the code invoking a method in DLL A, the code invoking a method in DLL B, and the code you invoke in both DLLs.  Also, `CreateInstance()` creates an instance of a type, not an assembly, so it is correct to use that.

Comment: You're currently trying to invoke a method on the type rather than on an instance of the type. It sounds like you need to get a reference to an existing instance of `ScriptEngine`, but without knowing more about it, we can't really help you any more than that.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes spot on, but I have not the slightest clue how I could go about doing that. If I were to pass a reference of the object as a parameter of Init would be preserved after invoking it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "preserved" here - but you have *much* more context than we do. If you have a reference to the right object, then yes, you should be able to invoke the method on it. In that case, do you really need to use reflection though? (At the very lest you could call `obj.GetType()` rather than loading the assembly etc.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton I do believe I do need to use reflection, reason being I am attempting to allow end users to customize their application via "scripting", this seemed much easier than embedding something like pawn or python. What I meant by preserved was if the reference to an object from one assembly is actually sent through invoke and not a copy of it etc. But it turns out that what I suggested did work. I appreciate you taking time out of your day to provide me the help you did though.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so the solution for me in this case was to pass the object that invoked Init along as a parameter with it. Thank you for the replies though!